# on every button click show same panel with usercontrol on it, again down of it

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

> on every button click show same panel with user-control on it has to display, again down of it

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebUserControl1.ascx.cs" Inherits="NBID2.WebUserControl1" %>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</td>
<td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

```js
> this is my my asp x page where on every link-button click same panel has to display again again

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
        </asp:Panel>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: in panel i want to link to usercontrol and display it on webpage on linkbutton click.on every button click in same  panel has to display usercontrol again.

Comment: on every button click same panel with usercontrol has to display..

Comment: please clarify again, your requirement seems confusing

Comment: In aspx page i had a button...on every buttonclick usercontrol.ascx has tobe displayed in aspx page.

Comment: can anyone please help me in solving above query..

Comment: how to make a usercontrol repeat when click on button(repeat same form down) and save in database when click on save_button.(using asp.net)

Comment: for example: i had a form when click on addnewform(button).. sameform has to display under it. 2)how to save each form in database.